# Why is data pre-processed with caret encoded as non-tabular objects

Tags: r, r-caret

I am learning how to use the R [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package, and I am wondering why there are than many functions that encode output data as objects that are non directly usable for training or regression.

For example, for [preprocessing](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html), the `dummyVars` functions returns an object of class "dummyVars". And similarly, the `preProcess` function returns an object of class "preProcess". These are non-usable by `caret::train`, and one has to work it out first with `stats::predict` like:

```
caret::dummyVars(Y ~ ., data = mydata) %>%
stats::predict(newdata = mydata)
```

Is there a reason for that? Why? What are the benefits?

Comment: This is more of a question for caret developer then for the SO community since it does not describe a problem than needs to be solved. Answers are going to be opinion based, so  I vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

After becoming more familiar with the package, I think I can provide an answer to this question and explain the advantages of such approach.

The `caret` package is intended to be used in a context in which one would not typically use just one predictive model to fit the data, but many.

Thus, objects such as `preProcess` are useful because they simply provide rules to process data than later can be passed to as many models as required. This saves coding and avoids errors (e.g. copy-pasting ones), because the same `preProcess` object can be used for all subsequent models in the `train` function by means of the `trControl` argument.

One must note also that these objects do not save entire "pre-processed" datasets (e.g. `dummyVars`, but just rules to be used during training, or during pre-processing. This also helps saving memory in a context where one might tend to accumulate many temporary variables and dataframes.